# Flyway JdbcTemplate exception logging

Tags: flyway

How can I get Flyway to output the stack trace of the exception occurred in the java migrator?

Apparently I can't.

```
    private Pair<Boolean, MigrationVersion> applyMigration(final ResolvedMigration migration, boolean isOutOfOrder) throws FlywayException {
    ...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error(e.toString());

        @SuppressWarnings({"ThrowableResultOfMethodCallIgnored"})
        Throwable rootCause = ExceptionUtils.getRootCause(e);
        if (rootCause != null) {
            LOG.error("Caused by " + rootCause.toString());
        }
    }
```

The stack trace is swallowed and that makes important information such as the line number of the exception disappear.

Are there any plans on changing this behavior?

Comment: if you need to know what is happening inside flyway maybe you can configure log4j to display flyway logs